# How to use SVM in Orange

Tags: machine-learning, orange

How to use [SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) in Orange for sentiments analysis? We will generate sentiments using sentiments analysis widget but now how to use SVM and how to teach SVM in Orange? i am use xlsx file format then it work good below example ... but i want to use text file (csv) format in which generate error target variable set how to remove this error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the output of the sentiment analysis to `Test&Score` widget together with `SVM` learner. `Test&Score` widget can perform different validations (e.g. cross-validation).

[image]

If you want to perform testing on different data please use `Predictions` widget. For more information please check widgets help available with pressing `f1` shortcut in Orange.

Comment: Above see my work is it true ??? and Plz suggestion about my problem which a mention.

Comment: The error on the `Test&Score` widget you get since you are connecting another corpus to SVM widget. In case you are using `Test&Score` widget SVM does not need an input. It just outputs the Learner. I do not understand the error you have. File widget should also accept CSV file.